# RealmSwift "Object has been deleted or invalidated"

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to design a button that allows users to "save" a listing on a collection view table. When the button is touched the listing's data is saved to realm and another view controller presents this data.

While I am able to get the data to persist onto Realm and show up and remove it if I tap the button again if I tap it the third time I get "Object has been deleted or invalidated", even if it's a different listing. Here's the code to give some insight into what I'm trying to do:

```
let lib = BookCollection()

let realm = try! Realm()

var unSavedBook = RealmBook()

func save(_ cell: HomeBookPreviewViewCell) {

    // This allows me to get the indexpath of a cell to use buttons on the collection view.

    guard let indexPath = self.bookListing.indexPath(for: cell) else {
        print("whaaaaaaa")
        return
    }


    if lib.Library[indexPath.item].saved {

        let savedBooks = realm.object(ofType: RealmBook.self, forPrimaryKey: lib.Library[indexPath.item].isbn!)
         try! realm.write {



            realm.delete(savedBooks!)

            //updates other view controller

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reload, object: nil)
        }

        cell.saveButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Star"), for: .normal)
        lib.Library[indexPath.item].saveBook(save: false)
    }
    else if (!lib.Library[indexPath.item].saved) {

        try! realm.write {
        //unSavedBooks is declared outside of function.

        //lib.Libary is an object that holds an array of Book objects with book attributes.

        unSavedBook.addRealmBook(lib.Library[indexPath.item].title!, lib.Library[indexPath.item].author!, lib.Library[indexPath.item].edition!, lib.Library[indexPath.item].publisher!, "\(lib.Library[indexPath.item].type!)", "\(lib.Library[indexPath.item].condition!)", "\(lib.Library[indexPath.item].subject!)", lib.Library[indexPath.item].seller!, RealmOptional<Float>(lib.Library[indexPath.item].price), lib.Library[indexPath.item].isbn!)

            realm.add(unSavedBook)

            //updates other view controller
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reload, object: nil)

        }




        cell.saveButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Star-Saved"), for: .normal)

        lib.Library[indexPath.item].saveBook(save: true)
    }
    print("Button tapped on row \(indexPath.item)")
}
```

I understand that I need to make the data load in with the saved boolean persisted, but i don't understand why it won't allow me to click for the third time.

Comment: Can you post more code? cause i am a bit confuse with multiple var like `lib.Library[indexPath.item].saved`. etc btw, can you post a couple screenshots, would be nice to have a clear idea

Comment: @PangHoMing Edited it to make it a little clearer, sorry for the messy code (i intend to delete it afterwards as there's another component i have to add.)

Answer (score 1):

You see this exception when you try to read the properties of the realm object that most likely has been deleted. Please make sure that you don't have any strong references to deleted realm objects or try to use `isInvalidated` property to handle that case.

Answer (score -1):

I used to use CoreData+Magical record when I develop iOS. And Realm only when i develop Android app.

Couple questions,

1. Like CoreData/other modern database, the result your fetched from realm queries are auto updated. (Ref: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#auto-updating-results). So, I am a bit confused with your `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reload, object: nil)` call. Also, can you show us your Collection View datasource delegate methods implementations? as there includes some Realm calls.
2. The 2nd question is about your app flow. From my understanding, there is a `Collection View`, each cell displays a `Book`. If you click the `Book` cell one, it presents another view to display the book info. And if you click it the second time, you delete the book. But if that book is deleted, how come use can click that cell the third time? Are you expecting the `Book` cell to be deleted or not? post a couple screenshot would be nice for us to help you :)